# How to start a program using a class to write a simple check bank balance?

Tags: python, loops, class, menu

I have to write a program to check a bank balance using a class. I first have to define a class named ‘Account’ with 5 attributes and initialize them. The five attributes are the user's input of their name, savings, checking, card, and limit. Is this how that is done?

```
class Account: 
    def __init__(self):
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        savings = 100
        checking = 20
        card = 10
        limit = 50
```

I eventually will have to create a menu, which will display the options as shown below:

Option 1: Check Balance
Option 2: Exit

The option 1(Check Balance), should call a function called check_balance() in order to show some information pertaining the account. I am just curious as to how I should start this.

Comment: You should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) additionally (or instead of the course). Your code snippet won't work because it assigns values to local variables instead of object attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your program involves creating 'instance attributes' for the Account class. To do this you need to add 'self.' in front of every instance attribute for the class in the constructor.

Next, to initialize this when you create an 'instance' of the class, you need to add parameters to the constructor that you can call when you create instances.

You can create methods inside the class by passing the parameter 'self' which indicates it is a method for the class.

Outside of the class, I would call 5 separate instances of the class and pass the parameters when you create the instance.

Here are some breadcrumbs to try.

```
class Account: 
    def __init__(self, name, savings, checking, card, limit):
        self.name = name
        self.savings = savings
        self.checking = checking
        self.card = card
        self.limit = limit
        
    def checkSavings(self):
        return self.savings

for _ in range(5):
    name = input("Enter name: ")
    savings = input("Enter savings: ")
    checking = input("Enter checking: ")
    card = input("Enter card: ")
    limit = input("Enter limit: ")
    
    # create instance of the class with paramaters
    account = Account(name, savings, checking, card, limit)
    
    # call a method of the class
    mysavings = account.checkSavings()
    print(mysavings)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I appreciate it. I’ll take that and run with it. I tried to get started and couldn’t figure out the first part about the class portion.